# Is Pex and Moles project still active?

Tags: .net, testing, moles, pex

They used to release a two new versions a month but since October 2010 they haven't released a new one. I've found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/e59d72ae-29fd-4251-a661-0c4ba2f58932).
But the fact they have closed its support forum on MSDN makes me suspect the project is not going forward.
We are using it for our current project, but we are thinking to replace it for another framework before it is too late.

Comment: Moles became Fakes and  now  available in  Visual Studio  Premium and Ultimate - see http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2919309-provide-microsoft-fakes-with

Answer (score 7):

We (the Pex team) has been quite busy working on productizing Moles. This will bring some changes to how things work internally, which has been delaying the next release of Pex. We are planning to release the next update in November 2011.

Comment: So no change of making the current version compatible with vs2010 sp1 before then?

Comment: @aL3891: Are you saying if I updated to vs2010 sp1, moles won't work? Our team is moving to VS2010 soon so I hope that isn't the case!

Comment: it does work with vs2010 prior to SP1, but after installing SP1 the MSTest agent runs into some kind of problem with the Moles test host, so any test with HostType("Moles") wont run.. everything compiles though, and stubs work fine, the problem is only with the Moles test host. Pex exploration might also work, as long as the tests doesnt use the Moles test host..

Comment: So it's November 30th 2011 and I don't see any updates.  Should we expect an update today?

Comment: They removed the November 2011 deadline from their site. I heard the next release has been scheduled to 12/21/2012. :-)

Answer (score 4):

According to the Pex [website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), a new version will be released in November 2011:

*...We are planning to release the next update in November 2011....*

Furthermore, they have a list of recent Microsoft blogs etc. (latest April 2011) so I don't think it's dead.

**Update:** From the Pex website:

*NEW: Code Digger for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 is a lightweight version of Pex that allows you to explore public .NET methods in Portable Class Libraries directly from the code editor. Under the hood, Code Digger uses the Pex engine.*

Comment: Thanks I was just wondering whether the project had been hold. A lot of things might happen until November'11. I think the list of blogs you mentioned is a list of external blogs, where you can add your own blog if it talks about Pex or Moles. It is the feeling they are delegating blog posts and forums to 3rd parties what makes me feel usure.

Comment: @Hero Yeah, I can understand that. Unfortunately, I'm not working at Microsoft so I can't make a better answer. However, one of the more recent blog-posts is MSDN UK.

Answer (score 1):

It is under active development, but support seems to be non-existent. Since they have made stackoverflow their default forum, a lot of questions seem to go unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Lightweight Pex for Visual Studio 2012 Portable Libraries called Code Digger.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikolait/archive/2013/04/23/introducing-code-digger-an-extension-for-vs2012.aspx