# Pex and Moles with MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, pex-and-moles

I was wondering if anyone has an opinion on whether it's worth it to spend much (any?) time obtaining and working with Pex and Moles, particularly for MVC 3 projects?

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976441/is-pex-and-moles-project-still-active):

1. Does Pex/Moles work with MVC? Anyone have any positive experience using it with MVC 3?
2. Should I wait until next release of Moles (November) to try and acquire it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether you can use Pex and Moles with MVC controllers actions than the answer is **yes you can**.

Especially Pex is an invaluable tool when it comes to testing because you don't have to write test code and the way it works it will definitely reliably cover whole code.

I haven't used Moles too much and depending on your code you may not need it either. In a layered application this shouldn't be a problem. Especially if you also write custom test code.

Maybe a more specific question would be better...